# How to calculate the sum of next 4rows in DolphinDB?

Tags: excel, data-analysis, dolphindb

I would like to calculate the sum of next 4 rows in DolphinDB. The result in Excel is as the picture show.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This will do:

```
t = table(1..100 as x)
select x, move(msum(x, 4),-3) from t
```